# ffmpeg 4 channel assignment with amerge

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I combine two stereo files to one 4 channel file with:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.wav -i 2.wav -filter_complex "amerge=inputs=2" -c:a pcm_s24le out.wav
```

This works fine, but when I open the file in Quicktime or want to edit it in other applications the quicktime channel assignment is L/C/R/SURR. But I want it to be QUAD - L/R/LS/RS. How can I tell ffmpeg to set these assignments?

Answer (score 4):

got it...

add

```
"amerge=inputs=2,channelmap=0|1|2|3:channel_layout=quad"
```

then Quicktime will correctly show the channels as L/R/SL/SR.